# Visual Basic 2010 Fast Writing

Tags: vb.net

I am working on developing a simple console game in Visual Basic in which the "level" is drawn out after being read from a file.

So far, I'm using

```
Console.ReadKey()
```

to check for the arrow keys and to therefore move the position of the piece on the console.

The problem is that the only way I know to do this is to redraw the "level" every time that the piece moves - which is relatively slow.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three solutions:

1. Redraw only the changing screen chars.
2. Skip Console functions and use WINAPI [WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (a little [example](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216395.html) to use WINAPI console functions).
3. Use Forms and draw the text into a window.